# Running a script that needs a package

Tags: packages, scripting, command-line

I am running a resource extensive notebook, and so I am trying to break it down into a .m file so that I can run it quicker and without using the mathematica interface. The problem is that my notebook needs another package (installed in the usual ~/.Mathematica/Applications/OtherPackage) and I cannot make it load with inside my .m.
The usual notebook normally calls the other package as

```
<< OtherPackage`
```

But if I add this to the beginning of the script and run

> $ math -script script.m

The output goes bananas.

On the other hand, if I start

> $ math

and then run

```
<< OtherPackage`
```

It loads correctly, and if later I perform

```
<< script.m
```

it behaves normally and runs as expected.

My question, is there a way to make my script run in a single go from the command line without having to go to the Tex-Base interface?

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "goes bananas"? Do you mean it doesn't load the package and you get errors from unevaluated expressions? Try using `Get["OtherPackage"]` instead of `<<`.

Comment: I used the Get["OtherPackage"] but the same thing happens. It's hard to explain what happens: there is an initial output confirming "OtherPackage" was loaded (it seems so), but then it processes the rest of the script faulty and with general stops, complaining about non-invertible matrices and arrays with unequal length, etc which I would interpret as "OtherPackage" not being successfully load...